# Confusion with multiple if/else statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm having trouble implementing multiple if else statements. I'm getting an error which says unexpected else.

Basically I need to check that a file has been entered, then if it has been entered checking needs to occur that it's not over the max size limit etc, then if it meets all that criteria it needs to be checked that it is either in a jpeg,jpg or png file type and then finally the database will be updated.

```
<?php
//this file uses the fields posted from the activity.html
//and stores it in the product_images table

$fileupload = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$filetype = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
$filesize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$tempname = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$filelocation = "images/$fileupload";

//make sure a file has been entered
if($tempname == "none") {
    echo "<p>You must enter a file " . mysqli_error($conn) . "</p>" ;
}
else
    {
        if (!move_uploaded_file($tempname,$filelocation)) {
            switch ($_FILES['userfile']['error'])
                {

                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                    echo "<p>Error: File exceeds the maximum size limit set by the server</p>" ;
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                    echo "<p>Error: File exceeds the maximum size limit set by the browser</p>" ;
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                    echo "<p>Error: No file uploaded</p>" ;
                    break;

                default:
                    echo "<p>File could not be uploaded </p>" ;
                }
    }
    else
            {
        if (($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES['userfile']['type']== "image/jpg") || ($_FILES['userfile']['type']== "image/png") ){

                    //image file is valid
                }
            }
        else
            {
        echo"Please upload file in one of these formats: jpeg,jpg or png.<a href='activity12-1.html'>Upload a file</a>";
            }
    }
else{
    //Open the company database and make sure the product_images table is present
    include ('companyDB.php');

    $dbQuery = "INSERT INTO product_images(imageurl) VALUES ('$filelocation')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $dbQuery))
        {
            echo"<h1>File Uploaded</h1>";
            echo"<p><img src='$filelocation' height='281' width='500'></p>";
            echo"The details of the uploaded file are shown below:<br/>";
            echo"<b>File Name: </b>$fileupload<br/> ";
            echo"<b>File type: </b>$filetype<br/> ";
            echo"<b>File size: </b>$filesize bytes<br/> ";
            echo"<b>Uploaded to: </b>$tempname<br/> ";
            echo"<a href='activity12-1.html'>Add Another file</a>";
        }
    else
        {
            echo "<p>Couldn't add the file to the database " . mysqli_error($conn) . "</p>" ;
        }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You have two `else` clauses for some of your `if` statements, perhaps because of mismatching braces.

Comment: Keep your code better formatted will help avoid issues like this in the future.

Comment: Yes my code needs better formatting, but I'm time poor and was just trying to do it as quickly as possible, although ironically now it will take longer. Nevermind. I'm thinking this whole thing might be easier if I use != for checking whether jpg, jpeg, png has been used, because then I can omit the extra else. (error would go underneath and then the else would open the database etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing curly brace.

This:

```
            default:
                echo "<p>File could not be uploaded </p>" ;
        }
}
else
{
```

should be this:

```
            default:
                echo "<p>File could not be uploaded </p>" ;
        }
    }
}
else
{
```

This is why it is important to maintain indentation consistency.

Answer (score 0):

According to me while laddering if-else the syntax is like this :

```
if(condition)
{

}   
else if(condition)
{

}
else if(condition)
{

}
else
{

}
```

And your code you had missed that @line 44

```
else
{
    if (($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES['userfile']['type']== "image/jpg") || ($_FILES['userfile']['type']== "image/png") ){

//image file is valid
    }
}
else
{
    echo"Please upload file in one of these formats: jpeg,jpg or png.<a href='activity12-1.html'>Upload a file</a>";
    }
}
else{
        //
```